# Android Webview JSInterface communicate with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, android-jsinterface

Is there any way, how the Web application, that was purely written in ReactJS, could communicate with the Android native application, that contains only webview, where I'm loading this ReactJS application? I couldn't rewrite the ReactJS app to React Native application, that is my only limitation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview#java

Comment: @rmanalo This is useless, I already described that the problem is in different technology's communication.

Comment: oh, really. sorry. that's the only thing I know. I haven't experienced using ReactJS

Comment: Vanilla js works fine, but not on react. but we really need to build our webapp with react. @jantursky got some solutions? it's been a whole year

Comment: It seems like nobody has any solution for this! It's easy to communicate from React Js to Android but from Android to React js it's impossible. And this just does not make any sense!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Cordova or any other container to serve your react.js web app as native mobile applicaiton.

Comment: But do you have the solution or way how to solve it in this type of case.